# Commands order and "Missing = inserted for \ifnum" error

Tags: macros, errors

I have a definition

```
\def\datetoint#1-#2-#3 {#1#2#3}
\def\lastrecorddate@debug{1970-01-01}
\edef\lastrecorddate{\expandafter\datetoint\lastrecorddate@debug{} }

\newcommand*{\record}[2]{%
    \edef\currentrecorddate{\datetoint#1 }%
    \ifnum\currentrecorddate<\lastrecorddate % <<--- ok
        \errmessage{%
            ...
        }%
    \fi
    ...
}

...

\record{2020-09-29}{Lorem ipsum}
```

It runs without error.
But if I swap the commands in the condition

```
\ifnum\lastrecorddate>\currentrecorddate
```

then the error `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` occurs. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the undesirable use of `{}` in

```
\edef\lastrecorddate{\expandafter\datetoint\lastrecorddate@debug{} }
```

Because of this, `\lastrecorddate` does not expand to a `<number>`, nor can its expansion be completed to form a `<number>`. However, a `<number>` is required before the comparison operator in `\ifnum` tests. When `\lastrecorddate` is put last, you don't see the problem because `{` being an unexpandable token, it finishes the `<number>` being read, then is skipped since the test is false here.

Because of TeX's parsing rules, I suggest you use something else than a space token to mark the end of the date. You can for instance use `\@nil` if `@` has category code 11 (letter).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\datetoint#1-#2-#3\@nil{#1#2#3}
\def\lastrecorddate@debug{1970-01-01}
\edef\lastrecorddate{\expandafter\datetoint\lastrecorddate@debug\@nil}

\newcommand*{\record}[2]{%
    \edef\currentrecorddate{\datetoint#1\@nil}%
    \ifnum\lastrecorddate>\currentrecorddate\relax % <- finishes a <number> to be extra safe
        \errmessage{Fake date?}%
    \fi
    No error.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\record{2020-09-29}{Lorem ipsum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Great! The `\relax` is not *necessary* here since `\errmessage` is unexpandable (thus finishes a started <number>), but is safer in case you would decide to replace  `\errmessage` with something that is not unexpandable (e.g., a macro) or simply starts with decimal digits (which would then be terrible).

Comment: Okay, I'll take that into account.

Comment: I changed the catcode stuff since you are apparently using LaTeX, not TeX. You should use `\newcommand` everywhere (or even `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends such as `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` in very recent LaTeX or with `xparse` in current LaTeX), because it won't silently overwrite existing macros or TeX primitives, contrary to `\def`. Well, for `\datetoint` which has a delimited argument, you can use `\newcommand\datetoint{}` followed by your `\def` to be safe.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't wish an already existing definition to be overridden in any case by `\def`, then don't do `\newcommand\datetoint{}\def\datetoint...` but do `\makeatletter\@ifdefinable\datetoint{\def\datetoint...}\makeatother`. `\@ifdefinable` will raise the same command-already-defined-or-name-\end...-illegal-error-message as `\newcmmand` in case the command is already defined or named `\end...`. But with `\@ifdefinable` the `\def` will only be performed in case the command both is not already defined and has a name which is allowed with commands in LaTeX 2e.